# How to read in a portion of a command line argument?

Tags: java, command-line, arguments

I’m trying to write a program that searches for keywords in a file and prints out all lines containing one or more of the keywords. The command line options include -i (makes the search case-insensitive.), -max n (prints out at most n lines.), and -k file (the file containing the keywords.)

When it works, java Search -max 10 -k keywords.txt input.txt,
prints the first ten lines of input.txt containing one or more keywords from keywords.txt. The comparison is case-sensitive since the -i option is not set.

I’m having trouble getting the keyword portion of my command line argument options to work. This is what I have so far. Any suggestions on how to get my program to work?

```
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class Search
        {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
          int max = -1;
          boolean insens = false;
          String keywordFile = null;
          String inFile = null;
          String keywords = " ";
          int count = 0;

       while (count < args.length)
       {
         String arg = args[count];
         if (arg.startsWith("-"))
         {
            String opt = arg.substring(1);
            if (opt.equals("max"))
            {
               count++;
               max = Integer.parseInt(args[count]);
            }
            else if(opt.equals("i"))
            {
               insens = true;
            }
            else if(opt.equals("k"))
            {
               ???
            }
            else
            {
               usage();
            }
         }
         else if (keywordFile == null)
         {
            keywordFile = arg;
         }
         else if (inFile == null)
         {
            inFile = arg;
         }
         else
         {
            usage();
         }
         count++;
         }

      Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inFile));
      while (in.hasNextLine())
      {
         String line = in.nextLine();
         if (contains(line, keywords, insens) && (max == -1 || count < max))
         {
            System.out.println(line);
            count++;
         }
      }
   }

   /**
      Checks whether the line contains one or more of the given words.
      @param line a line
      @param words a list of words
      @param insens true if the comparison should be case-insensitive
      @return true if line contains one or more of words
   */
   public static boolean contains(String line, ArrayList<String> words, boolean insens)
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(line); 
      in.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z]+");
      while (in.hasNext())
      {
         String wordInLine = in.next();
         for (String word : words)
         {
            if (insens && wordInLine.equalsIgnoreCase(word) || wordInLine.equals(word))
            {
               return true;
            }
         }
      }
      return false;
   }

   /**
      Prints a message describing proper usage and exits.
   */
   public static void usage()
   {
      System.out.println("Usage: java Search [-i] [-max n] -k keywordfile file");
      System.exit(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the input and what is the output? Any error/exception? Did you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify input and output. I made sure to edit in a second paragraph that explains what the program should produce.

Comment: What do you mean by *having trouble*?

Comment: It appears your question is not about searching a file at all;  what you seem to need is a way to read a keyword file into an ArrayList of Strings.  Is that correct?

Comment: Just some thoughts on that. 
As you want to search for keywords in an input file you should remove the '-k' option and have the cmd line like 'Search [-i] [-max n] keywords.txt input.txt' as keyword file needs to be provided.
Also the keywords vaiable should be a ArrayList as stated in contains method. And you need to be clear about the format you have the keyword file be written in like line sepparated or csv... and a method where you read the keywords in your array list.